# Strange holes next to foundation

Tags: foundation, rodent

First time posting here.This morning I was inspecting my house and found these two holes next to the foundation.

My friend suggested to insert a stick to see how deep they are.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this? Not sure if I should be concerned.

Also you'll notice pieces of concrete around the foundation. That's because I attempted to seal the house holes I could find along the foundation in summer time when we first moved in and didn't clean it up.

First time home owner :)

Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some kind of insect?   They're the right size for hornets but they usually make more of a mess around the hole.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? I'm not sure this can be answered without a little more information or context.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I'm in Connecticut, temperatures lately have been around 57 degrees at night, 70's during the day.

Comment: Install one of those wildlife cameras near the holes and see if anything comes out :)

Comment: shove mothballs into the holes.

Comment: Yes I'm planning to install a camera to see exactly what it is. Could mothballs cause more harm than good?

Comment: @MiguelE  They are not good for young kids to eat, so precautions are required(don't let the kids see them).

Comment: Bugs that eat a perfect circle in concrete seems unlikely. Could it be unfilled concrete form ties?

Answer (score 1):

Did cicadas emerge this year in your area? These look like [cicada holes](https://www.google.com/search?q=cicada%20holes&tbm=isch), which are made when the cicada emerges from the underground stage of its life cycle in search of a mate. If this area is shielded from rain, the holes could have been there since mid-summer, when cicadas typically emerge.

If these are cicada holes, there's nothing to do but clean up. Cicadas don't return to the same hole.

Comment: Could be cicada killer wasps too. But those hang around a month or two and are hard to miss. (They’re very large)